# Google sheets sumifs with multiple conditions not working as expected for splitting and summing across months

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where I am managing personal finance, and for calculations I am using few formulae, everything is working except for one formula which isn't working.

I want to split the expenses month-wise for a specific category, when I use condition to sum all the expenses for that category across all the months, it works fine giving me the total

Here's the sample page:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQu9tKuCP2GU7apEtX3Gp6xCb7K1THl0dDCXEiqu0bU/edit?usp=sharing

Example:

```
=SUMIFS('Other Expenses'!E2:E,'Other Expenses'!C2:C,"Eat out",'Other Expenses'!G2:G,TRUE)
```

The above formula gives me how much I spent for "Eat out" category across all the months. But when I try to split among months, it doesn't happen.

I have tried a few things like the below, with no luck unfortunately.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('Other Expenses'!C2:C&'Other Expenses'!A2:A,"Eat out"&'IF(TEXT('Other Expenses'!A2:A,"MMMM-YYYY")=C2)','Other Expenses'!E2:E))
```

```
=QUERY('Other Expenses'!A1:G,"Select A,C,E where A > date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C = 'Eat out'",1)
```

Query gives me the filtered list of all the expenses for a category, "Eat out" in this case, but I am unable to process it further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

FYI: I am not an expert on sheet or excel, this is just something which I do for personal tracking.

Comment: You will find many people ready to help out, but you need to make it simple for them. Always include a sample data sheet with the expected result (i.e. how it should look like at the end), so they can have a look at it and suggest a solution, otherwise you're asking them to guess your situation, for which they may waste time because of a wrong guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion :)
I agree to your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wanted to filter your data by `Category` or by `Description`, in any case you can easily change the columns as needed and try the following:

[image]

See your spreadsheet tab called Nabnub: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQu9tKuCP2GU7apEtX3Gp6xCb7K1THl0dDCXEiqu0bU/edit#gid=756080617)

**First Formula in A7:**

```
= {query({ArrayFormula(PROPER(text('Other Expenses'!A2:A, "MM-MMMM"))),'Other Expenses'!B2:B,'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col1 ,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&A6&"'
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc label sum(Col3)
           'Total', Col1 'Months'"); 
   {"TOTAL 2021",SUMIF('Other Expenses'!B:B,A6,'Other Expenses'!E:E)}}
```

**Second Formula in A22:**

```
= {query({ArrayFormula(PROPER(text('Other Expenses'!A2:A, "MM-MMMM"))),'Other Expenses'!C2:C,'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col1 ,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null and Col2='"&A22&"'
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc label sum(Col3)
           'Total', Col1 'Months'"); 
   {"TOTAL 2021",SUMIF('Other Expenses'!C:C,A22,'Other Expenses'!E:E)}}
```

**Third formula in D7:**

```
= {query({'Other Expenses'!B2:B,'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col1 ,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc label sum(Col2)
           'Total', Col1 'By Description'"); 
   {"TOTAL 2021",SUM('Other Expenses'!E2:E)}}
```

**Fourth formula in G7:**

```
= {query({'Other Expenses'!C2:C,'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col1 ,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc label sum(Col2)
           'Total', Col1 'By Category'"); 
   {"TOTAL 2021",SUM('Other Expenses'!E2:E)}}
```

**Fifth formula in J7:**

```
= {query({ArrayFormula(PROPER(text('Other Expenses'!A2:A, "MM-MMMM"))),'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col1 ,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1 Order By Col1 asc label sum(Col2)
           'Total', Col1 'Months'"); 
   {"TOTAL 2021",SUM('Other Expenses'!E2:E)}}
```

**Sixth formula in M7:**

```
= {query({ArrayFormula(PROPER(text('Other Expenses'!A2:A, "MMMM"))),'Other Expenses'!B2:B,'Other Expenses'!E2:E}, 
   "Select Col2 ,sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null and Col1='"&M6&"'
        group by Col2 Order By Col2 asc label sum(Col3)
           'Total', Col2 'Months'"); 
   {"TOTAL",SUMIF(ArrayFormula(PROPER(text('Other Expenses'!A:A, "MMMM"))),M6,'Other Expenses'!E:E)}}
```

Comment: I am looking to filter by Category and this is amazing, Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can also add some graphs for your own convenience.

Comment: Wow, that is really nice, I really really appreciate the help. 
I was looking for some workaround solution for to manage my personal finance, and I got something that looks very very professional.
I am now curious to dig deep into this. I will try to understand the formula and learn it

Thank you very much sir/ma'am :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the simpliest solution is to perform a pivot table. And then group by monthes and categories.